Bibliography title in line with references
I am writing an article where I want to keep my References section in a single paragraph (i.e., no line breaks). I have managed to remove line breaks between entries following the answer to this question. However, the title "References" still appears on a separate line before the first reference.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%remove line breaks between bibliography entries
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}{\item[\hfil\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}]}{\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}\space}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\citep{placeholder,placeholder2}

\setlength{\labelsep}{-1em}
\bibliography{refs}

\vspace{5mm}

\noindent \textbf{References.} [1] Author, P. 2023, Placeholder Journal. [2] Author, P. 2024, Placeholder Journal.

\end{document}

In the attached image, the top two lines show how my bibliography appears currently, but I want it to look like the bottom line (typed manually to illustrate). Is there any way to do this? I have tried editing the .bst file with no luck, and also adding and removing space after the bibliography title, but if I do that I can't get the first entry to be indented.


Welcome to TeX.SE. Please confirm that you wish to employ the article document class. And, do please reveal which bibliography style you intend to use.

I do wish to use the article document class. I'm using a .bst file adapted from the Standard Nature style (sn-standardnature.bst). I've made some changes so that the references appear as above (author, year, journal) with no italics or bold text.

You meant sn-nature.bst, not sn-standardnature.bst, right?

The file I inherited is called sn-standardnature.bst - looking at the latest Nature Overleaf template I think it's called sn-nature.bst. The style appears to be the same.

To change the size and placement of the "References" header, it suffices to run \renewcommand\bibsection{\par\bigskip\noindent\textbf{\refname}. I'm afraid I can't figure out, though, how to suppress the line break that follows.
